# How can I select look a like id names from SVG using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, svg

Currently I have elements with id name of `CDT-B2-1, CDT-B2-2, and CDT-B2-3`

I want to select those 3 by using document.querySelector()

P.S
I use this code `` document.querySelector(`[id="CDT-B2-*"]`) `` but it didn't work.

P.P.S
element id names are dynamic so it will not always `CDT-B2-1, CDT-B2-2, and CDT-B2-3` but sometimes it can be `CDT-B2-10, CDT-B2-20, and CDT-B2-27`

Comment: try `[id ^= "CDT-B2-" ]` (begin with) or `[id *= "CDT-B2-" ]` (contains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector code to

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='CDT-B2-']");
```

From [Substring matching attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> [att^=val]
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

The docs also include selector syntax to find attributes with a specific suffix `[att$=val]` or a substring value `[att*=val]`.

Answer (score 0):

To select elements that start with a certain `id` you can use `[id^="CDT-B2-"]`. Furthermore you need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) since it will return all elements instead of the first one it finds.

Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for all possible attribute selectors.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="CDT-B2-"]');

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div id="CDT-B2-1"></div>
<div id="CDT-B2-2"></div>
<div id="CDT-B2-3"></div>
```